# Add text to matrix row or column

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

Can a single column and row be highlighted within a matrix ? Would like to add some text and arrow that describes a given row within a matrix, something like :

[image]

latex code for above matrices :

```
\begin{gather*}
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
*
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{gather*}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very easy with `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{%
    myarrow/.style = {-Stealth, shorten >=5pt}
} 
\newcommand{\mypoint}[2]{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0, anchor=base](#1){$#2$};}}

\begin{document}
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    \begin{gather*}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ \mypoint{here1}{1} & 2 & 3
    \end{bmatrix}
    *
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & \mypoint{here2}{3} \\ 1 & 2 & 3
    \end{bmatrix}
    \end{gather*}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node[below=30pt of here1](textofhere1){some text};
      \draw[myarrow] (textofhere1) -- (here1);
      \node[right=30pt of here2](textofhere2){some other text};
      \draw[myarrow] (textofhere2) -- (here2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace{7ex}

    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but rendering on Overleaf shows arrows overlapping the text : https://www.overleaf.com/12495476fvqytcsgtntn , is this not related to your code and is something related to Overleaf ?

Comment: @blue-sky I see your link correctly, is it exactly where you got the problem?

Comment: yes, i can see it also fine, maybe an issue with my browser, anyway all good now, thanks!

Comment: @blue-sky I've edited my answer. Please note that I removed `\overlay` from `\mypoint` macro. It was wrong, mainly because it could give problems when the cell text is larger than the others. Now it always works.

Answer (score 3):

With `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} %% to compile with pdflatex --enable-write18 (MiKTeX) or pdflatex -shell-escape (TeXLive, MacTeX)

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{pspicture}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 2 & 3 \\ \rnode{B}{1} & 2 & 3
    \end{bmatrix}
    *
    \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 2 & \rnode{T}{3} \\ 1 & 2 & 3
    \end{bmatrix}
    \psset{labelsep = 2em, nodesepA = 0.3ex, nodesepB = 0.8ex, arrows = ->, arrowinset = 0.12, linewidth = 0.6pt, linecolor = Tomato}
    \everypsbox{\color{Tomato}}
    \uput[r](T){\rnode{T1}{\text{Text1}}}\ncline{T1}{T}
    \uput[d](B){\rnode{T2}{\text{Text2}}}\ncline{T2}{B}
  \end{pspicture} \]

\end{document}
```

(If you don't want to compile with `pdflatex`, remove  loading of `auto-pst-pdf`)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If it's OK to have the arrows above the matrix, you could (ab)use the `gmatrix` environment from the `gauss` package to place them. Two possibilities for making the arrows are shown.

No `\vspace` required.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,gauss,tikz}
% modify some things in gmatrix environments
\renewcommand\rowmultlabel{}
\renewcommand\colmultlabel{}
\setlength\rowarrowsep{0pt}
\setlength\rowopminsize{0pt}
\begin{document}
Some text text text text and so on.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{gmatrix}[b]
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  1 & 2 & 3
\colops
\mult{0}{\begin{array}{c}\text{text 1}\\\downarrow\end{array}}
\end{gmatrix}
\!*
\begin{gmatrix}[b]
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  1 & 2 & 3
\rowops
\mult{0}{\leftarrow\text{text 2}}
\end{gmatrix}
\end{equation*}
More text text text text text and so on.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{gmatrix}[b]
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  1 & 2 & 3
\colops
\mult{0}{\tikz\draw[<-](0,0)--(0,5mm)node[above]{text 1};}
\end{gmatrix}
\!*
\begin{gmatrix}[b]
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  1 & 2 & 3
\rowops
\mult{0}{\tikz[baseline=(a.base)]\draw[<-](0,0)--(5mm,0)node[name=a,right]{text 2};}
\end{gmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```