# Formatting arrows and text under a matrix

Tags: formatting, symbols, matrices

I am looking to be able to write this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9bMe.jpg

but I'm a little stuck with the arrows and what not concerning the arrows underneath the matrix. I've got this so far:

```
 \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    \square & \square & \square & \square 
    \\   $\uparrow$
    \end{pmatrix}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404387/add-text-to-matrix-row-or-column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz}
\newcommand{\Poss}[1]{\ifnum#1=1
\tikz[remember picture]{\node(node-#1){$\scriptscriptstyle
\begin{array}{c}#1~\text{possi-}\\
\text{bility}\end{array}$}}
\else
\tikz[remember picture]{\node(node-#1){$\scriptscriptstyle
\begin{array}{c}#1~\text{possi-}\\
\text{bilities}\end{array}$}}
\fi}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    \square & \square & \square & \square 
    \\   \uparrow & \uparrow &\uparrow &\uparrow \\
    \Poss{4} & \Poss{3} & \Poss{2} & \Poss{1} \\[-1.6cm]
    \end{pmatrix}\]
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2,3,4}
{\path (node-\Y) -- (node-\X) node[midway]{$\scriptstyle\times$};}} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much. Never would have got this!

Comment: @marmot -- if it doesn't throw off the alignment too much, a much better word break would be "possi-bilities"

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, you are right. The language of humans will always remain difficult for me, ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the tabular environment instead of a matrix.
Here is my solution:

```
\documentclass{article} 


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}

  \multirow{2}{*}{$\biggl($}

  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &

  \multirow{2}{*}{$\biggr)$} \\
  & $\square$  & $\square$  & $\square$  & $\square$  & &\\
  & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & &\\
  & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\makebox[0pt]{$\times$}}}{\parbox{7ex}{\small 4 possibilities}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\makebox[0pt]{$\times$}}}{\parbox{7ex}{\small 3 possibilities}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\makebox[0pt]{$\times$}}}{\parbox{7ex}{\small 2 possibilities}}
  & {\parbox{7ex}{\small 1 possibilities}}
  & =
  & $4!$ possibilities \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

This is what I obtain:
[image]

Comment: Good +1. Can you edit your answer because possibilities is not in math mode?